# Select statement that divides arbitrary data into buckets that sum up to a specific value

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a way in an Oracle database of dividing some amount of money into several buckets into equal parts and then making sure that the sum of money is equal to initial one with single `SELECT` statement?

Maybe some fancy combination of aggregate functions?

For example: we have an amount of 100 dollars and 3 time buckets. I need the query to result in something like

```
(33.33, 33.33, 33.34)
```

So the last value equilibrates everything there.

Example data:

1. period start data 01/01/2015
2. period end date   01/01/2016
3. total volume      121 tons

I need SQL command to output equally distributed Total Volume among all months so I get at the end:

Jan - 10
Feb - 10
...
Nov - 10
Dec - 11

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: Please explain the logic. Do you need to do INTEGER allocation to buckets? Your first example divides 100 into 33.33, 33.33 and 33.34, why doesn't the second example divide 121 tons into 10.08, 10.08, ... , 10.08, and the last one 10.12 to make up the 121.00 total? Why is it integers here, but not in the first example? THEN, assuming you actually want integers - should all the "overage" (extra stuff) go to the last bucket, or be spread evenly over the last few buckets? If you had 122 instead of 121, should 11 months get 10 and the last one 12, or should the first 10 get 10 and the last two 11?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a table of time buckets, then just use window functions:

```
select 100.0 / count(*) over () as bucket_amount
from buckets b;
```

Note that this gives an equal amount to all three, so there is no 33.34.  It can be tweaked for that purpose, but you really need to provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

**Query**:

```
SELECT month,
       FLOOR( lvl * volume / num_months ) -
         FLOOR( (lvl - 1) * volume / num_months ) AS bucket
FROM   ( 
  SELECT     volume,
             FLOOR( MONTHS_BETWEEN( end_month, start_month ) ) AS num_months,
             ADD_MONTHS( start_month, LEVEL - 1 ) AS month,
             LEVEL AS lvl
  FROM       (
    SELECT 121 AS volume,
           DATE '2015-01-01' AS start_month,
           DATE '2016-01-01' AS end_month
    FROM   DUAL
  )
  CONNECT BY ADD_MONTHS( start_month, LEVEL - 1 ) < end_month
);
```

**Output**:

```
MONTH                   BUCKET
------------------- ----------
2015-01-01 00:00:00         10 
2015-02-01 00:00:00         10 
2015-03-01 00:00:00         10 
2015-04-01 00:00:00         10 
2015-05-01 00:00:00         10 
2015-06-01 00:00:00         10 
2015-07-01 00:00:00         10 
2015-08-01 00:00:00         10 
2015-09-01 00:00:00         10 
2015-10-01 00:00:00         10 
2015-11-01 00:00:00         10 
2015-12-01 00:00:00         11
```

Comment: If you change volume from 121 to 122, then June will get 11 and December will get 11. This doesn't seem consistent with the OP's requirement (but, the requirement is not entirely clear as I expressed in a comment to the original question - I would hold on any extra work until he/she clarifies the requirement first).